# Set featured image from auto generated video thumbnail url php

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

```
// Set video generated thumbnail as featured image***

if(isset($posted_data['video-file']) && $posted_data['video-file'] != ''){
              //Wait 10 seconds for thumbnail to be generated   
               sleep(10);
              //  $file_location = '';
                if(!$contact_form_7){
                    $file_location = $posted_data['video-file'];
                } else {
                    $file_name = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$filename."_thumb1.jpg";
                    $uploaded_files = $contact_form_7->uploaded_files();
                    $file_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$filename."_thumb1.jpg";

                }
                $res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $new_ID, $file_name);

            }
```

Comment: Sorry this posted all wrong. I'll try this again.

Answer (score 0):

`set_post_thumbnail()` requires the second parameter to be an `int` for attachment `id`, so the statement `$res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $new_ID, $file_name);` does not work.

First you need to add the image to your database as an attachment and then you will be able to use its `id` to set it as thumbnail.

See [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/#user-contributed-notes) for more help and detail to set an image as featured image.

Comment: Your correct. The auto generated thumbnail preview is created by ffmpeg which is done when the video is uploaded. It adds this image into the media library which I am trying to retrieve to set it as the featured image on my video blog post. Because this image is already in the library, I am trying to figure how to get its "post id" to use as the "attachment id" and use the "$file_name" as its file path.

Comment: You get the `attachment_id` when image is added to media library using `wp_insert_attachment()`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. So if I have my video file that is IMG_0676.mp4 and the auto generated preview from that file is IMG_0676_thumb1.jpg with a Post_ID of XXX which is already in the media library, to get this file should I use wp_get_attachment_image_url(Post_ID (which would be the new attachment_ID) ) as the $file_location?

Comment: Can you share te code where the generated thumbnail is inserted into media library. This will help in explaining the issue. thanks.

Comment: This is the code that auto generator uses to produce the first frame of the video and then add it to the media library.      $thumbnailfilename[$i] = $jpgpath.$sanitized_url['basename']."_thumb".$i.".jpg";

  $thumbnailfilename[$i] = str_replace(" ", "_", $thumbnailfilename[$i]);

Comment: Once this process is completed then it does:    
  $tmp_thumbnailurl = $thumbnailfilebase."_thumb".$i.'.jpg';

  $tmp_thumbnailurl = str_replace(" ", "_", $tmp_thumbnailurl);

  $final_thumbnailurl = str_replace('/thumb_tmp/', '/', $tmp_thumbnailurl);

Comment: if ( is_file($thumbnailfilename[$i]) )

  kgvid_schedule_cleanup_generated_files('thumbs');

Comment: $thumbnaildisplaycode = '<div class="kgvid_thumbnail_select" name="attachments['.$postID.'][thumb'.$i.']" id="attachments-'.$postID.'-thumb'.$i.'"><label for="kgflashmedia-'.$postID.'-thumbradio'.$i.'">

Comment: <img src="'.$tmp_thumbnailurl.'?'.rand().'" width="200" height="'.$thumbnailheight.'" class="kgvid_thumbnail"></label><br /><input type="radio" name="attachments['.$postID.'][thumbradio_'.$postID.']" id="kgflashmedia-'.$postID.'-thumbradio'.$i.'" value="'.$final_thumbnailurl.'" onchange="kgvid_select_thumbnail(this.value, \''.$postID.'\', '.$movieoffset.', jQuery(this).parent().find(\'img\')[0]);"></div>';

Comment: That's all of it.

Comment: Can you see generated image in WP dashboard->media-> library?

Comment: Yes. it comes in as IMG_0676_thumb1.jpg . This is an example.

Comment: then there must be a call to  `wp_insert_attachment( )` in your code. can you find it?

Comment: Yes.  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_location, $new_ID );
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_location );
                    $res1 = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
                    $res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $new_ID, $attach_id );

Comment: Also, the new_ID is the newly created id from the submitted post which the image (set as the featured image) will be attached to.

Comment: and here is where the file_location would be specified:                     $file_name = "file name of auto generated thumbnail";
                        $uploaded_files = $contact_form_7->uploaded_files();
                        $file_location = "file path of auto generated thumbnail";
      
                    }
                                       
                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file_name, null );
                    $attachment = array();

Comment: Yes, if this code exist then it should set the image (`$attach_id`) as thumbnail for post (`$new_ID`). And there is no need to add `$res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $new_ID, $file_name);` in code included with your question.

Comment: Question is, how to find the path to the file in the media library. I was thinking about this code because I am having trouble pointing to the Post_ID after the file is generated to add it to the new blog post:    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.sanitize_file_name($filename)."_thumb1.jpg";
                        $file_name = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file);
                        $uploaded_files = $contact_form_7->uploaded_files();
                        $file_location = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file);

Comment: [See this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) to find the path to the file in the media library. `$attach_id` should be passed as first parameter.

Comment: That did it. Thank you Qaisar. You are awesome.

Comment: @Marcus Stay blessed.

Comment: Many blessings to you as well.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, do accept as Accepted Answer and up-vote. Thanks. This will help other find the solution.